# Ansible pip module issue reading requirements.txt file

Tags: pip, ansible

I am using Ansible's pip module to install my applications dependencies from a requirements.txt file. Its definitely working, going down the list and installing each package, but when it gets to one in particular, it will fail causing the whole ansible-playbook to fail with an Ascii unicode error.

Ansible-Playbook task

```
- name: Install project requirements
  pip:
    state: latest
    requirements: "{{ project_path }}/requirements/base.txt"
    virtualenv: "{{ venv_path }}"
    virtualenv_python: python3.6
    virtualenv_command: /usr/local/bin/virtualenv
```

Ansible Message

```
Collecting django-s3direct==1.0.3 (from -r /srv/app/requirements/base.txt (line 35))
Downloading django-s3direct-1.0.3.tar.gz (61kB)
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File \"<string>\", line 1, in <module>
File \"/tmp/pip-build-ab20m5jb/django-s3direct/setup.py\", line 5, in <module>
readme = f.read()
File \"/srv/xena/.virtualenv/lib64/python3.6/encodings/ascii.py\", line 26, in decode
return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 6326: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on the code from django-s3direct, it tries to read the README.md, which seems to be encoded in UTF8. It fails because python tries to read it with an ascii codec.

Try to change the default encoding for python, run this in your console to set the env variable:

```
export PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8
```

edit: since the error appears on the guest, set the env variable in your playbook: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_environment.html

```
- name: Install project requirements
  pip:
      environment:
        PYTHONIOENCODING: utf8
```

Comment: Hey Syl, I'm not sure if it matters where you run the export command, but I tried it with "export LC_ALL=C", as well as your suggestion, and unfortunately neither of them work.

Comment: Is there a command that shows you what your environment variables are, or is there a file you have to look into ?

Comment: you can type `env` to check your env variables. the export command like that will only be valid in your current terminal. If you want to set it globally, you may want to update your .bashrc file. I guess your error appear on the guest, so yeah, definitely in the .bashrc.

Comment: I can see its in my environment variables, but it still doesn't want to install. hmmmm

Comment: I edited my answer, you may be able to set the env in the playbook.